# Angular print element height and width in ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-repeat

Well basicly as the title says...

```
<td data-ng-repeat="j in [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]">
    Height:{{this.height}}, Width:{{this.width}}
</td>
```

But `this` refer to $scope and not the `<td>` itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the directive approach, maybe something like this? Change the html to

```
<td data-ng-repeat="j in [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]" dimensions>
    Height:{{height}}, Width:{{width}}
</td>

.directive('dimensions', function() {
    return {
        link: function(scope, elem) {
            scope.height = elem[0].offsetHeight;
            scope.width = elem[0].offsetWidth;
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: what is directive appended to, app? (app = angular.module('studentApp', ['ngRoute']);) If true I guess this approach didn't worked [link](https://student.sps-prosek.cz/~eisead11it/web/IS/Student/#/)

Comment: There is a function() too much in Zack's example, otherwise it works fine: http://plnkr.co/edit/peoIK9Ucxj3OBm17EMkH?p=preview